# Jaspersoft Studio issue with subreports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am having an issue while attempting to compile my Main report which consists of a Sub report in Jaspersoft Studio.

This is the error I am getting:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get next record from result set.
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:524)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$20(ReportControler.java:499)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get next record from result set.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource.next(JRResultSetDataSource.java:134)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.advanceDataSource(JRFillDataset.java:1422)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1271)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1250)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1010)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:558)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:119)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: The result set is closed
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.checkOpen(AbstractResultSet.java:233)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.checkCursorMove(AbstractResultSet.java:222)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.next(AbstractResultSet.java:284)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource.next(JRResultSetDataSource.java:130)
... 8 more
```

I have looked all over the internet and have looked in every Stack Over Flow question that may help with this and I am still coming up short.

Any information on this issue will be greatly appreciated!

-Colt

Comment: Did you try the same connection (firebirdsql) for simple reports?

Comment: If possible can you please edit your question to include the jrxml code where you include the subreport in your report and some relevant code of your subreport.

Comment: @AlexK yes it's the exact same connection :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here can be in 2 areas.

1. How you created the JasperReports data source that you pass into the report

   This is in the code you are using to run JasperReports. The JasperReports Server manages the creation and transaction control for data sources. What is the Firebird JDBC URL you are using?
2. How you pass the connection to the sub report

This is in the JRXML. When you use the sub report, you have to add:

```
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
```